# Update DE using data from BuildRowsetFromXml

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml

I have an xml export that I need to use in order to send email to the users from the xml, to separate the ContactName in to FirstName and LastNameand and also to update a DE. The content of the xml is in the DE in the first row.

Since this is my second day since I started using AMPScript, I am pretty sure that I did something wrong.

[image: xml in the DE]

```
%%[
<root>
    <Customer CustomerID="1657"> 

      <CompanyName>AMO Food Market</CompanyName>

      <Industry>Retail</Industry>

      <ContactName>Anne Mollin</ContactName> 

      <ContactTitle>Marketing Manager</ContactTitle> 

      <Email>anne.mollin@AMOFoodMarket.com</Email> 

      <FullAddress> 

        <Address>2732 Daver Str.</Address> 

        <City>Bandie</City> 

        <Region>OR</Region> 

        <PostalCode>94215</PostalCode> 

      </FullAddress> 

    </Customer> 

    <Customer CustomerID="1986"> 

      <CompanyName>Folimi Tires</CompanyName>

      <Industry>Cars</Industry> 

      <ContactName>Adrian Moods</ContactName> 

      <ContactTitle>Sales Representative</ContactTitle> 

      <Email>adrian.moods@folimitires.com</Email> 

      <FullAddress> 

        <Address>City Mall 100 Main St.</Address> 

        <City>Dondie</City> 

        <Region>OR</Region> 

        <PostalCode>93210</PostalCode> 

      </FullAddress> 

    </Customer>

</root>

var @xml,@Name, @FirstName, @Email, @LastName, @CustomerID, @CompanyName, @Industry, @ContactName, @ContactTitle, @Address, @City, @Region, @PostalCode

set @xml = AttributeValue("xml")
set @xml = ""
set @FirstName = AttributeValue("FirstName")
set @Email = AttributeValue("Email")
set @LastName = AttributeValue("LastName")
set @CustomerID = AttributeValue("CustomerID")
set @CompanyName = AttributeValue("CompanyName")
set @Industry = AttributeValue("Industry")
set @ContactName = AttributeValue("ContactName")
set @ContactTitle = AttributeValue("ContactTitle")
set @Address = AttributeValue("Address")
set @City = AttributeValue("City")
set @Region = AttributeValue("Region")
set @PostalCode = AttributeValue("PostalCode")

BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, 'CompanyName', 1)
BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, 'CustomerID', 1)
BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, 'Email', 1)
BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, 'Industry', 1)
BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, 'ContactName', 1)
BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, 'ContactTitle', 1)
BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, 'Address', 1)
BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, 'City', 1)
BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, 'Region', 1)
BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, 'PostalCode', 1)


set @ContactName = AttributeValue('ContactName')
set @Email = AttributeValue('Email')
set @FirstName = substring(@ContactName,1,subtract(indexOf(@ContactName,' '),1))
set @LastName = substring(@ContactName,ADD(indexOf(@ContactName,' '), 1),Length(@ContactName))
UpsertDE('AMPscript Functions 3', 1, 'Email', @Email, 'FirstName', @FirstName, 'LastName', @LastName, 'CustomerID', @CustomerID, 'CompanyName', @CompanyName, 'Industry', @Industry, 'ContactName', @ContactName, 'ContactTitle', @ContactTitle, 'Address', @Address, 'City', @City, 'Region', @Region, 'PostalCode', @PostalCode)


]%%

Hello 2 %%=v(@FirstNAme)=%%.



Welcome to our community.

Have a great day!
```

Comment: Based on the multiple checkboxes in your screenshot, it appears the XML is actually spread across multiple rows instead of just "the first one." This will make parsing the XML with the `BuildRowsetFromXml` function rather cumbersome as it's not being fed a "complete picture." How is the raw XML currently being imported into this data extension? I would get this first part of the process (a complete string of XML in one row) sorted first, before proceeding to the next step (using AMPscript to parse/separate values then write to potentially a separate data extension).

Comment: In the code above is the original XML (between <root> and </root>). As for importing in the DE, I've copied the data and pasted it in to a csv file and then imported it in to the DE. Since the xml data does not come in to a string form, I don't know how to tackle it.